# Java String in JSON

Tags: java, jquery, json, response

I have a problem. I am submitting a form using `JSON(Jquery)` and setting value in a `String` variable in `Java` Class. I want to show that String in alert box in Jquery. Here is my Code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "//action",
    data: {
       //datas......
    },
    contentType: "//",
    dataType: "//",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.RegisterMessage);
    },
    error: function (msg) {}
});
```

**PROBLEM IS :**

I am getting alert from success portion but getting 'undefined' every time. I want the String in alert box that is set in java class.

Here is my java code :

```
  public String RegisterAction(){
        RegisterMessage = processAction.RegisterAction(userbean);
        return "success";
 }
```

`RegistrMessage` variable contains a String, cant get it :( 
.. Hope you can help

Comment: You are `return "success";` and `dataType: "json",`. try with `dataType: "text",`

Comment: Why would you expect to get back an object with a `RegisterMessage` property, as opposed to simply the string you returned?

Comment: from java code you are returning only string, so how can you get RegistrMessage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the solution to my problem. In the Java class, I generated the getter and setter method for that String `RegisterMessage` and the rest of my code worked fine afterwards.

Thanks to everyone that helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning a string. Your code should be like this to display your success message.
 `success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }`

Try this it might help you. You are returning a string and expecting an object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are returning a string back from your server ie : "success" and in your method with the argument which is msg you are trying to access a property named RegisterMessage which does not exist and hence you are getting undefined.

To correct it ... You would then have to return something like this from your server response.

```
   {
    "register_message": "Ya now ok"
   }
```

And now you would access it in your method in js using

`msg.register_message`.

**NOTE:**

But make sure you convert this string into an object in your js first using a library like jsonify as from server you are sending a text content only or instead change the content type on server.

Comment: Nope , nothing works.And For the guys who voted down the question, do you know the answer? Share the correct answer for others like myself then vote down the question, If you don't know the answers dont vote a question down

Comment: What error do you get now ? And post what you have changed now in the code

Comment: I chose the best answer for the question, see above. it works

Answer (score 0):

From java code you need to return String in json format as:

{"RegisterMessage":"success"}